# AWS-Managed Directory Service, DHCP service can't be configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, domaincontroller

I've created an AWS Managed Active Directory with the following:

- Directory DNS name : ad.example.com
- Directory NetBIOS name : ad

I need to create a DHCP server on this AWS service and its domain controllers.

I have a Windows Server "Management" instance. I RDP into this machine with my Admin account that was created with the AWS Active Directory.

- Username : ad.example.com\Admin

After logging in, I go to Server Manager, add roles and features, and install "DHCP Server" and related tools.

For some reason, I can't access the DHCP server on the AWS domain controller from this management instance.

For example, I have DNS Server enabled, and I was able to access the AWS domain controller's DNS server and settings, by going to DNS Manager, clicking on "Connect to DNS Server", typing, ad.example.com. After that, ad.example.com showed up as a DNS server in "DNS Manager" and was able to manage the DNS server.

When I try to do the same in DHCP Manager and add ad.example.com as a DHCP server, it doesn't work. After adding that domain, there's an error message saying "Cannot find the DHCP Server". I also tried adding a DHCP Server with the IP addresses of the Domain Controllers but the same thing happened as before with ad.example.com.

Why can't I connect/setup DHCP on my AWS-Managed Microsoft AD Domain Controllers?